# django stripe set up installation error

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

My problem is down to my lack of experience with django (and coding) and stripe.

I am trying to test a very basic stripe payment on a test form on my local development server, but I am getting an error message when I try to start my local development server.

Here is a a screen grab of the issue:

[image]

**Can somone give me an idea of what I have done wrong and how I even start to go about solving the issue? I am using [djstripe](https://github.com/pydanny/dj-stripe) which I have pip installed.**

I have searched my templates and gone over my code and SO and Google, but I am still stumped. I have djstripe installed in my INSTALLED_APPS.

**Is there a tutorial of how to read and interpret the errors in the above screen grab, or does the understanding mainly come from experience?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY (and STRIPE_SECRET_KEY I believe) in your settings.py. You can get this key from stripe if you have an account.

If you follow the instructions you will see this. https://github.com/pydanny/dj-stripe

A google search for "reading python stack trace" gives us this:
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-read-and-understand-errors-from-tracebacks-9704

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will follow through with this.